# What is the positive variation of a function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, bounded-variation, total-variation

I am having trouble understanding what the positive variation of a function $\frac{ 1}{2} ( T_F + F)$ represents. (Where, in this case, $T_F$ is the total variation of $F$ from $[0,x]$.) For consider $F = 1-x$ on $[0,1]$. In this case $T_F(x) = x$. Therefore The positive variation of this function is $\frac{ 1}{2} ( T_F + F) = \frac{ 1}{2} ( x + 1-x) = \frac{ 1}{2}$ on the entire interval $[0,1]$. What does this represent? (The notation I am using here comes from Folland's Real Analysis.)

Comment: Well, the positive variation is a function that that is supposed to "capture" the increasing part of $F$ - it only goes up when $F$ goes up. As your $F$ only ever decreases, $T_F$ never increases, i.e. it stays stuck at whatever value it has at $0$, i.e. it's constant. As to why that constant is $1/2$, that's a bit more complicated, but basically that lets the negative variation be the smallest possible function. Do you understand what the neg. and pos. variation provide a solution for?

Comment: @JonathanZonstrike I get that the difference between the positive and negative variation functions return the original function. I guess I just assumed they had some kind of intuitive visual that connected it back to the original function, which I guess isn't the case, and didn't think about it again until now. The negative variation in this case is $\frac{1}{2} ( T_F - F) = \frac{ 1}{2} ( x -1 + x) = x - \frac{ 1}{2}$, which also doesn't intuitively connect back to the original function $1-x$ for me. But I guess I shouldn't try to think about it that way?

Comment: For me, the "visual connection" is that the pos. variation increases when $F$ increases, and stays constant when it decreases, and the neg. variation only changes when $F$ decreases, and it matches $F$ going down by going up the same amount. That creates a visual image for me, especially if I imagine the three functions being drawn simultaneously, starting from zero.

Comment: That said, this particular $F$ is incredibly boring (it's purely decreasing), and maybe if you worked out what happens with $\sin(x)$, or some wiggly fourth-degree polynomial, it might give a  picture that provides more insight.

Comment: Oh, I realized that I incorrectly used $T_F$ for "positive variation". Wish I could correct that in the first comment, please excuse any confusion that might have caused.

Comment: @JonathanZonstrike I thought about using sin(x) at first to get a more helpful image of the positive and negative variations. But these functions are not exactly computable for $F (x) = \sin(x)$, nor could I find a visual already created. Any idea how to get that? I only used this boring function to clearly highlight the point I was confused about.

Comment: Hmmm, I thought there would be some nice examples out there, but my quick search gave me nothing.  Yeah, you're not going to find a nice closed expression for anything interesting - they're all going to have piecewise definitions.

Comment: I'd suggest skipping expression as a formula, and concentrate on the graphs of the functions. Draw three separate x-y axes, one on top of the other. Graph sin(x) on the bottom one, and then start from x=0 and start graphing the pos and neg variations on the top two. Remember both are non-decreasing, and only one of them increases at a time, and which one depends on whether F is increasing or decreasing.